# Downpass self: cannot borrow `self` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to downpass a mutable object, so that the entity responsible for working and managing certain aspects of the application can change parts of the world... for example make a bunny appear if a particular item fades away.

```rust
pub struct World {
    world_items: WorldItemManager
}

impl World {
    pub fn new() -> World {
        World {
            world_items: WorldItemManager{},
        }
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        //
        // Uncomment to make it fail:
        //
        //self.world_items.process(&mut self);
    }
}

pub struct WorldItemManager {
    // items, events, anything that it should own
}

impl WorldItemManager {
    pub fn process(&mut self, _world: &mut World) {
        // If the sun stands at the exact spot, it makes something in the _world appear.
        // Also: yes, if I don't take a _world argument it compiles. But.. that's the point.
    }
}

struct Game {
    world: World
}

impl Game {
    pub fn new() -> Game {
        Game {
            world: World::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        loop {
            self.world.process();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut game = Game::new();
    game.run();
}
```

I know that I can fix this by..

- not passing the World at all
- making the World not mutable in the manager
- putting all the logic of the manager directly in world

I'm not looking for those, as I just want to find out how I can have a normal object graph where I can downpass what needs changing without making everything so cumbersome. It should be simple, but I can't get it to work:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.world_items` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         self.world_items.process(&mut self);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------^---------^
   |         |                |       |
   |         |                |       first mutable borrow occurs here
   |         |                first borrow later used by call
   |         second mutable borrow occurs here
```

How can I downpass myself to a child of myself?

Comment: What you're trying to do is in fact unsafe from a type perspective: what if `process` tries to mutate `world.world_items`? Then you have two mutable references (one from `&mut self` and one from `&mut world.world_items`.

Comment: @Aplet123 So then nothing can ever mutate state it doesn't directly own? How can I then introduce side effects without using Redux? I know that's far fetched but surely I'm not supposed to have event buses go all the way up in the chain just to deliver the message to a secondary component? If a component can only mutate its own state, global state is immutable, and I can't have side effects, then how can I structure a program that isn't a single struct within a single file?

Comment: *"So then nothing can ever mutate state it doesn't directly own?"* - No, just you're not allowed to mutate yourself and your parent at the same time. Rust doesn't give you the potential to do anything unsafe (like deleting the child while processing it). However, you don't have to resort to redux-style patterns, the usual escape hatch for "I know it *would* be unsafe for me to mutate the same thing twice, but I *promise* I won't do it" would be to use [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html)s.